# passportjs: user undefined, req.isAuthenticated() is false

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, passport.js

**Note: there are many similar questions but I've gone through all of them and none of the solutions work.**

Hi, 
I've tried every solution on the net, bug still persists.

I'm building a simple CRUD app, and I'm currently struggling with passportjs's req.isAuthenticated().
The user is definitely being authenticated, as console.log(req.user) in passport.authenticate returns the user object, and req.session.passport has the user id.

After the redirect though, even if the redirect is async, user is undefined and req.session.passport is empty. It's as if the session is reset.

Here's the code:

app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/bootstrap', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist')));

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 5 * 60 * 1000
  }
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require("express-messages")(req, res);
  next();
});

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.method, ":", req.url);
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});

app.use("/", index);
app.use("/users", users);

var port = 4000;
app.listen(port);
module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  if (req.user) {
    console.log(req.user.username);
  }
  res.render('homepage');
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  console.log("passport: ", req.session.passport); //passport:{}
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/users/login');
}

module.exports = router;
```

users.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('usersDB', ['users']);
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var passport = require('passport'),
  LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;​
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.render('login');
});​
router.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
  res.render('signup');
});​
router.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
  db.users.findOne({
    username: req.body.name
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    if (user) {
      console.log("nope");
      req.flash("error", "Username taken. Choose a different username.");
      return res.redirect('/users/signup');
    }
    var password = req.body.password;
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        var user = {
          username: req.body.name,
          email: req.body.email,
          phone: req.body.phone,
          password: hash
        }
        db.users.insert(user, function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          console.log("registered", user)
          res.render("homepage", {
            user: user
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
}); //sorry for the callback hell..works fine
​​
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  return done(null, user._id);
});​
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  db.users.findOne({
    id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)
  }, function(err, user) {
    return done(err, user);
  });
});​
passport.use('loginStrategy', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true,
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(req, username, password, done) {
    db.users.findOne({
      username: username
    }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', "Invalid username."));
      }
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password,
        function isMatch(err, isMatch) {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          if (!isMatch) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error', "Oops. Incorrect password."));
          }
          return done(null, user, req.flash('success', "Welcome " + user.username + ", you are now logged in."));
        });
    });
  }​));​
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('loginStrategy', function(err, user, info) {
    if (info) {
      req.flash('error', info.message);
    }
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      //callback redirect after saving session.
      req.session.save(function() {
        console.log(req.session.passport); //{ user: 59ceb263dae7a4270087ae57 }
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});​
router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/users/login');
});​
module.exports = router;
```

I would really appreciate some help, as this is seems to be a common bug, but none of the workarounds work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the method you are using to store the user creds. Please note, Chrome and IE have different quirks about local vs session storage. Try this in chrome, Passport JS will store the response in either Local or Session storage - you should interrogate those storage mechanisms to verify the user's credentials are in them.

In chrome, go to the F12 debug tools and look in your session and local storage:

[image]

Please let us know the browser you are using, and if using Chrome makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using chrome V61.0.3163.100 to begin with, but didn't work on Firefox either. Checked in both session and local storage. both are empty, which is puzzling..